# SingleChildScrollView is not Scrollable

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add SingleChildScrollView for the page but it appears to be not working, can't figure the reason. I am not getting any overflow errors as such but the Fitbutton is not visible on the screen. I tried searching on the net but didn't find any relevant solution.
This is the code snippet I tried:

```
return Scaffold(
        body:SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
                key:_formKey,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          decoration:( ...
                           ),
                          )
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                          
                          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.10,
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                            child:Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text("Welcome",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25.0),),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 22,
                                  ),
                                  Stack(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        height:60.0,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 53.0),
                                        child: buildNameField()
                                      ),
                                      CircleAvatar(
                                        ...
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 22.0,
                                  ),
                                  Stack(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    children: [
                                      .....
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Stack(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    children: [
                                      ...
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  
                                  SizedBox(height: 22),
                                  FitButton(
                                    ....
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                                    child: _buildSignInButton(),
                                  ),
                                ]
                            ),
                          ),
                      ),],
                  ),
                ),
              ),),
     );
```

Any help would be great !!

Answer (score 0):

Remove SingleChildScrollView from Form and
Wrap to Column may be solved.

Comment: No, that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `form` in a `sizedBox` and then wrapping the `sizedBox` with the `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: That didn't help either

Comment: @MrunalJoshi can you add a screen shot of the button